# Cannot register in quarkus-security-webauthn: Cookies are not added to /q/webauthn/callback call

Tags: quarkus, webauthn, quarkus-security-webauthn

## General Setup

I have a VUE/Javascript web frontend running on https://localhost:3001

This web-app is communicating against an backend via API calls to https://localhost:8443  My backend is a quarkus java application.

I would like user's to be able to register and login with FaceID/Fingerprint, ie. [WebAuthn](https://webauthn.guide).

I am debugging both the frontend and the backend locally on my dev machine. Both are setup with HTTPS/TLS.

## My Problem

I cannot get the WebAuthn registration to work. I am trying to follow this quarkus-webauthn guide: https://quarkus.io/guides/security-webauthn#writing-the-html-application

When I try to register as a new user, then two requests are sent:

#### First request /q/webauthn/register

The first request is the initial request for registration

```
Summary
URL: https://192.168.7.67:8443/q/webauthn/register
Status: 200
Source: Network
Address: 192.168.7.67:8443
Initiator: 
quarkus-webauthn.js:116

Request
:method: POST
:scheme: https
:authority: 192.168.7.67:8443
:path: /q/webauthn/register
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 65
Content-Type: application/json
Host: 192.168.7.67:8443
Origin: https://localhost:3001
Referer: https://localhost:3001/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.1 Safari/605.1.15

Response
:status: 200
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://localhost:3001
Content-Length: 478
Content-Type: application/json
Set-Cookie: _quarkus_webauthn_challenge=DOfcXyce7gqKBSoJefnOxN28kSTye8OwwFK+giBhFebR9vsYz/Xnw06B9AFxzhSLSHiUjxHawDlCAGEEmdVJAZmP/stfvAKCNKn+5firpIRdq3Q9JDegWSj8w6F4RIyqhmRQjsofZ0GwaHMX/OeRSWdEWOgf3C7uy+lO/t7MQFEk; Path=/; Secure; SameSite=None
Set-Cookie: _quarkus_webauthn_username=DH78nSuxY8ago0Lcz3L/q2Z3+K91ZTN3eohSFEm4wAcs2ip3XYvIddcp4KI/3nV2p8oZMaGKtAnUXzOhPs9cSoD9X9LU; Path=/; Secure; SameSite=None
```

Please take not of the two cookies that are returned by the quarkus-security-webauthn library. These cookies *should* be set and stored in my local browser. I am not sure if they are....

#### Authenticate with FaceID / Fingerprint

After the first request my browser does popup the authentication window, where I can authenticate via FaceID.

#### Second request: /q/webauthn/callback

Then the frontend sends a callback back to the backend. But this fails:

```
Summary
URL: https://192.168.7.67:8443/q/webauthn/callback
Status: 400
Source: Network
Address: 192.168.7.67:8443

Request
:method: POST
:scheme: https
:authority: 192.168.7.67:8443
:path: /q/webauthn/callback
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 608
Content-Type: application/json
Host: 192.168.7.67:8443
Origin: https://localhost:3001
Referer: https://localhost:3001/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/17.1 Safari/605.1.15

Response
:status: 400
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://localhost:3001
Content-Length: 6258
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

Take note that this request does not contain the two cookies that the first request returned. But the backend seems to require them.

## Error message

The log in my quarkus java backend shows:

```
ERROR kusErrorHandler.handle(QuarkusErrorHandler.java:134) | HTTP Request to /q/webauthn/callback failed, error id: c98ddf92-2859-4d7e-a0f9-2fe66044b435-1:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing challenge or username   at
io.quarkus.security.webauthn.WebAuthnController.callback(WebAuthnController.java:218)
```

This is the [relevant source code from the quarkus-security-webauthn library](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/49046457d5005b3c22e490d56017054726e7680b/extensions/security-webauthn/runtime/src/main/java/io/quarkus/security/webauthn/WebAuthnController.java#L214):

```
RestoreResult challenge = authMech.getLoginManager().restore(ctx, CHALLENGE_COOKIE);
RestoreResult username = authMech.getLoginManager().restore(ctx, USERNAME_COOKIE);
        if (challenge == null || challenge.getPrincipal() == null || challenge.getPrincipal().isEmpty()
                || username == null || username.getPrincipal() == null || username.getPrincipal().isEmpty()) {
            ctx.fail(400, new IllegalArgumentException("Missing challenge or username"));
            return;
        }
```

## Some more details and my configurations

#### Versions

Everything on the newest version as of December 25th, 2023  e.g. io.quarkus:quarkus-security-webauthn:3.1.3.Final

#### Configs

`application.properties`

```
quarkus.webauthn.enabled=true
quarkus.webauthn.cookie-same-site=none
quarkus.webauthn.origin=https://localhost:3001

# My CORS config
quarkus.http.cors=true
quarkus.http.cors.origins=/.*/

# Is this necessary? Required? Helpfull? Does not matter at all?
quarkus.http.cors.access-control-allow-credentials=true

# I already tried A LOT to get my frontend to return and send these two cookies
# No luck so far
quarkus.http.same-site-cookie._quarkus_webauthn_challenge.value=none
quarkus.http.same-site-cookie._quarkus_webauthn_username.value=none
```

## Questions

- Is my assumption correct at all? Do these two cookies need to be sent with the second `callback` request?
- Is HTTPS a precondition for WebAuthN?  It really seems to be.

  - Only for the frontend?
  - Or also for the backend API?
  - Or only the backend API?
- Why are these two cookies not stored in my browser. Event not if I debug right after the response to the first "register" request. I really(!!!) tried to set everyting. Same-Site: Lax, None, ...
- What is the correct CORS configuration for my setup. Because my frontend and backend run on different ports?

#### Things I *already* tried

- Run from http => does not work. So update everyting to use HTTPS / TLS
- Run frontend and backend from local intranet IP-address => Does not work
- Run frontend and backend from localhost (but two different ports => does not work
- Run everything from hostname => does not work
- Configure dozens of things around CORS, same-site cookies and headers in quarkus application.properties => still no luck

As I said I am serving my VUE frontend as a standalone application. When I serve the webAuthnLogin.html file (from the quarkus-security-webauthn guide) directly from META-INF/resources from my quarkus backend then the webauthn registration works. So I really suspect this is some kind of CORS issue. But how to circumvent it?

PLEASE HELP!